# How to rollback multiple databaseChangeLog file at once

Tags: liquibase, rollback

I perform a liquibase update command with a given ChangeLog XML file and tag it with tag1.

For example:

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=... --changeLogFile=change1.xml update
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=... --tag tag1
```

I then perform several additional updates commands with other ChangeLog XML files:

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=... --changeLogFile=change2.xml update
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=... --changeLogFile=change3.xml update
```

Now I would like to rollback to tag1:

```
liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --url=... --changeLogFile=??? rollback tag1
```

Which file should I specify in `--ChangeLogFile`? Is there a way to define multiple files? Is there a way Liquibase can store embed the rollback commands without the need to supply the update XMLs?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using multiple changelog files from the command line, typical usage is to just have one changelog file that is used for the whole application. It is possible to have multiple changelogs, but in that pattern you have a single 'master' changelog that then includes other changelogs. see https://www.liquibase.org/bestpractices.html for some examples of this.

When rolling back, liquibase needs to know what the actual changes are, so it can then do something else to do the rollback. The DATABASECHANGELOG table does not store the actual contents of each changeset that has been applied, it just keeps the id, author, filepath, and a checksum. It has no way of knowing that changeset id `123778` by `steve` in file `changelog.xml` was a create table or an alter column or anything. So the changelog file MUST be there to be able to roll things back.

For certain change types like 'create table', Liquibase can 'automatically' generate a rollback for you - it is just 'drop table'. But if the change was something like 'drop table', it cannot generate a rollback - drop table command only has the name of the table to drop, and doesn't know what columns were in that table, etc.

So that is why Liquibase requires that you always supply a changelog file, and if you want to be able to do rollbacks, you may also need to specify how to roll back each change.

Comment: So If I rollback >1 changeSets which have been defined in multiple changeLog files, I need to provide the rollback with a single changeLog XML which contains the multiple changeSets provided during the update.

Comment: Exactly. I recently wrote a blog post about "fixing problems" here - might help explain things: https://www.liquibase.org/2019/12/5-ways-fix-bad-database-change.html